# Is it possible to let mouse events pass through a canvas layer?

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of images and a canvas layer on top of it, I would like to do some animations on the canvas tag once the user rolls over a thumbnail image from the grid, so I wonder if is possible to let mouse events pass through the canvas layer?

Comment: Why do you have a canvas on top of everything?

Comment: Because I want to do an animation on top of the image(s) that triggers the mouse event

Comment: So why not just create a canvas over an image upon a mouse over event?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this css property on your canvas:

```
pointer-events: none
```

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#pointer-events

It is intended to prevent the element from receiving any mouse events at all.  Mozilla seems to believe that the event will pass through to elements behind it like you are hoping.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events

It looks like this may not be supported in IE and Opera, so you might have to disable your animation in those browsers.

Comment: Seems to be safe to use nowadays: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events At least if you don't care about IE<=10 ;)

Comment: Can this be done per-object in a given canvas? Such that you can layer canvas-on-canvas and be able to click upper objects (top canvas) and lower objects (bottom canvas)?