# IE9 Forward mouse events through a masking canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, internet-explorer-9, jquery-events

My absolutely positioned canvas elements are blocking all the mouse events so that nothing underneath them can be clicked, same problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861430/is-it-possible-to-let-mouse-events-pass-through-a-canvas-layer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009753/pass-mouse-events-through-absolutely-positioned-element).

I have multiple canvas layers that need to be at specific z-index's so I need to forward mouse events through the canvases. `pointer-events: none;` works in good browsers, but for IE9 I need javascript to do it, here is my current solution,

```
 var evts = [ 'click', 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'dblclick'],
                canvases = $('canvas');

            $.each(evts, function(_, event){
                canvases.bind(event, function(evt){
                    var target,
                        pEvent;
                    $(this).hide();
                    target = document.elementFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY); 
                    $(this).show();
                    pEvent = $.Event(event);
                    pEvent.target = target;
                    pEvent.data = evt.data;
                    pEvent.currentTarget = target;
                    pEvent.pageX = evt.pageX;
                    pEvent.pageY = evt.pageY;
                    pEvent.result = evt.result;
                    pEvent.timeStamp = evt.timeStamp;
                    pEvent.which = evt.which;
                    $(target).trigger(event, pEvent);
                 });
            });
```

Working example,
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WMXh/3/)

Questions;

**1. I'm creating the new event and passing over the relevant data, would it be safe to pass the `evt` var with the target and currentTarget modified?**

**2. How can I propogate a right click?**

Or does anyone have a better way to accomplish this? The other related questions are quite old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *clean* way to pass the events cross-browser. You can pass the (modified) event on but you can't guarantee that it will work as it might have naturally, especially cross-browser.

For right click using your code just do this: http://jsfiddle.net/6WMXh/20/

(you half used the jquery extra info part but never did anything with it)

Comment: I'm am trying to send events through the canvas, not into the canvas. In IE9, any element underneath the canvas does not get click events passed into it. You can see what I mean [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VvPPW/1/) in IE9.

Comment: Oh derp, I didn't notice the elements below were non-canvases! I've edited my answer but the sad fact here is that there's still no golden way to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to add a check so it would also work for the element not under the canvas, `e.button == 2 || pEvent.button == 2`. Dam, I hate IE...