# How to pass events through a canvas to underlying HTML

Tags: html, events, canvas, mouse, masking

I need to create a canvas that is mostly transparent, ie masks the underlying HTML .. I need mouse events to go to the canvas and the HTML underneath ... The canvas is almost full size of the browser window

Is it possible to do this ?

Update:
It needs to be cross browser

...pointer-events: none is not cross browser...is there any other way? –

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to let mouse events pass through a canvas layer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861430/is-it-possible-to-let-mouse-events-pass-through-a-canvas-layer)

Comment: @John Please let us know if the linked question solves your problem.

Comment: no ..it needs to be cross browser...pointer-events: none is not cross browser...is there any other way?

Comment: @John Can you please mention this in your question?

Answer (score 0):

**It might be possible...and here's a totally untested and ugly attempt at it.**

You mention cross-browser compatibility, so jQuery is useful here.

Here's the plan:

- Have jQuery listen for mouse events on the canvas.
- When fired, get the mouseX and mouseY.
- Get a reference to the jQuery event object.
- Get a set of jQuery objects containing each element at mouseX/mouseY.
- Use jQuery to trigger the event on each element in that set.

This is a possible starting point...and probably needs tweeking.

Here's some untested code for the click event:

```
// pre-calc the offsets of the canvas
var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

// on canvas click, 
// get all elements under the click
// and trigger the click event on them

$("#mycanvas").click(function(e){
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // get a referenct to the jq click event object
    var mEvent=$.Event('click');                       // added '.'

    // get a set of all elements under mouseX/mouseY
    var elements=elementsAtXY(mouseX,mouseY);

    // trigger the event on each element under X/Y
    elements.each(function(){
        $(this).trigger(mEvent);
    });

});



function elementsAtXY(x,y){
    var $elements = $("body *").map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var mleft = offset.left;
        var mtop = offset.top;
        var height = $this.height();
        var width = $this.width();
        var mright = mleft + width;
        var mbottom = mtop + height;

        return (y>=mtop && y <=mbottom) && (x>=mleft && x<=mright) ? $this : null;
    });
    return $elements;
}
```

If the elements on your page don't move, you could improve performance by pre-calculating the position of each element instead of calculating it during each event.

Comment: Very novel idea but not practical